# Free way to convert PDF to XPS with C#

Tags: c#, pdf, xps

Are there any **free** tools that I can use to convert a PDF document into an XPS document?  Although a nice programmatic API would be nice, I'm not opposed to shelling out to a command line tool to do the conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbcPdf version 7 includes this funcationality, if you link back to their site you can have a free license key.  Utilize the save method to accomplish PDF - XPS conversions.

XPS is exported only if the supplied path ends with ".xps", and it requires the .NET Framework 3.0.  XPS is supported via Doc.SaveOptions.FileExtension of the Save method when saving to a stream. Set this property to either ".xps" or "xps" otherwise a conventional PDF output will be generated. XPS streams must have FileAccess.ReadWrite and not simply FileAccess.Write otherwise the operation will fail.

```
virtual void Save(Stream stream)
```

Comment: That seems to be to import XPS to PDF ... I need it the other way around ... I have a PDF and need it to be an XPS

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited above to reflect what you're after

Comment: If you don't link back to their site you'll need to pay (i think the base cost is around $350) otherwise you can get a free license

Comment: Public Shared Sub ConvertPdfToXps(ByVal pdfPath As String, ByVal xpsPath As String)

        Dim doc As New Doc()

        Dim xr As New XReadOptions()

        xr.ReadModule = ReadModuleType.Pdf

        doc.Read(pdfPath, xr)

        doc.SaveOptions.FileExtension = "xps"

        doc.Save(xpsPath)

    End Sub

Comment: after further review... ABCPDF's functionality in converting from PDF to and other file format requires the Pro license which is $239 for a single developer machine.